# Boolean for whether a string contains a substring

Tags: filemaker

Suppose I have a text variable `$$string`.
How can I write a boolean to check whether `$$string` contains the text `$$substring`?

*e.g. if $$string is "foobar" and $$substring is "oo", then the result should be True, and if the $$string is "foo" and $$substring is "bar" the result should be False.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a problem like this I'm partial to the PatternCount function:

```
 PatternCount($$string ; $$substring)
```

You should then get back false = 0 or true >= 1. You can force true to 1 as follows:

```
 PatternCount($$string ; $$substring) > 0
```

Function Definition here: http://fmhelp.filemaker.com/fmphelp_10/en/html/func_ref3.33.73.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Position](http://www.filemaker.com/11help/html/func_ref3.33.74.html) function:

```
Position($$string;$$substring;1;1)>0
```

Note: `Position($$string;$$substring;a;b)` checks whether $$substring is contained at least *b*-times in $$string from starting position *a*, and returns where the *b* th occurrence is located in $$string, or *-1* if there is no *b* th occurrence. Counting starts from *1*.

Comment: FileMaker text positions are 1-indexed, and 0 is used to indicate that the selection is out of range. So you need to modify your function slightly: Position( $$string; $$substring; 1; 1) > 0